# How to find the armijo step length in a neural network using binary cross entropy loss?

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

I am using the binary cross entropy loss function to train a neural network. With the help of the pytorch library, I am calling nn.BCELoss(). I am trying to compute the armijo size step length. The formula for checking the armijo step length is given as follows -

```
f(x + lr*v) <= f(x) + c*ß*func_gradient , where lr is the learning rate and v is the descent direction
```

I have all the parameters but how to call the function f(x) or f(x+something) considering the loss function as binary cross entropy?

Comment: In the context of neural networks `x` corresponds to the model parameters, i.e. all the weights and biases encapsulated in a single variable. To evaluate `f(x + lr*v)` you first need to perturb the model parameters by `lr*v`, evaluate the training data with the updated model, then calculate the loss.

Comment: In that case my model will be updated twice. Once in order to calculate the armijo step length f(x+lr*v) and then again to update the model after getting back the armijo step length from the formula. Is it correct to update the model twice in every epoch? Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: You would potentially have to update the model more than twice in order to do the line search, as long as you ultimately leave it in the state where the condition is met. You could create a deep copy of the model (something that isn't necessarily trivial, depending on the model), perform the line search by perturbing the copy and then ultimately update the original model just once with the appropriate step once found. Imo it would make more sense to perturb the original model just to avoid the overhead of the copy.

Comment: Worth pointing out that pytorch provides the `LBFGS` optimizer which performs a line search. You can either use that or look at the implementation ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lbfgs.html#LBFGS)). For this optimizer to work you must provide `step` with a closure function that reevaluates the model on the training data and returns the loss.

Comment: Thank you! But I cannot use the optimizer as I am finding the descent direction with the help of an optimization formula. I need to only calculate the step length in order to reach the convergence of the neural network. Can I compute the value of the loss function without updating/committing the changes on the neural network? I mean other than following the deep copy method you mentioned earlier. Is there any possibility of implementing the "test" step by storing the old weights, updating them(x+lr*v) and compute the loss?

Comment: You can copy state dictionary of the model and then load it at the end of the search. Something like `old_state_dict = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())` then after you finish the line search you can do `model.load_state_dict(old_state_dict)` to get back to the original model state. If you're asking if you can evaluate `f(x + lr * v)` without updating actually evaluating the model then you can't generally do that.

Comment: @jodag - Since f(x) is changing everytime in the line search, I need to calculate the gradient also everytime. However, the direction of descent v is going to be the same everytime f(x+lr *v) > f(x)+.... . Everytime this condition is satisfied, lr=lr/2 has to be done and I need to calculate f(x),f(x+lr*v),gradient of f(x) again. Is the v constant throughout the line search?

Comment: Assuming a standard line search, then you shouldn't need to calculate the gradient each time since the Armijo rule uses the gradient of `f` evaluated at `x` (not at `x + lr * v`). Line search generally means you search in the same direction (along a line) to find a suitable step, so `v` should be fixed.

Comment: yes true but in case of the neural network x is always changing as we are committing the changes in our network model. So x becomes (x+lr*v) then 2*(x+lr*v) till the line search is satisfied. So should I also do f(x) in the next iteration=previous iteration f(x+lr*v) ? I mean as the x is always changing?